# Issue with Sprite

Tags: python, pygame

1. The issue I am currently having is that my image appears to be filling the screen with itself, how can i fix this issue?

   ```
   import pygame, os, sys
   from pygame.locals import*

   pygame.init()

   sHEIGHT = 600
   sWIDTH = 800
   gName = "Survive"

   fps = pygame.time.Clock()
   FPS = 10

   GD = pygame.display.set_mode((sWIDTH,sHEIGHT))
   class Main:
   white = (255,255,255)

   def display(white):
       pygame.display.set_caption(gName)
       GD.fill(white)
   def player1():
        img ="Images/"
        health = 100
        global movex
        global movexchange
        global movey
        global moveychange
        global imgplayer1
        movex = 400
        movey = 400
        movexchange = 0
        moveychange = 0

        imgplayer1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img, "Human.png"))




        pygame.display.update()                         


   def gameLoop():
       fps.tick(FPS)


       while True:
           print(fps)
           global movexchange
           global moveychange 
           global movex
           global movey
           for event in pygame.event.get():
               if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                         pygame.quit()
                         sys.exit()  
               if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                   if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                          moveychange = 0
                          movexchange -=5
                   if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                          moveychange -=5
                          movexchange =0
                   if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                          moveychange += 5
                          movexchange = 0      
                   if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                          moveychange = 0
                          movexchange +=5     
               if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:           
                   if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                        movexchange =0
                        moveychange =0
                   if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                        movexchange =0
                        moveychange =0
                   if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                        movexchange =0
                        moveychange =0
                   if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                        movexchange =0
                        moveychange =0           


           movex +=  movexchange
           movey +=  moveychange
           GD.blit(imgplayer1,(movex,movey))
           pygame.display.update()


   display(white)
   player1()
   gameLoop()
   ```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening and how i can solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyGame is low-level library.

You have to clear screen before you blit objects in new places. You can use some image as background or you can use `fill(color)` to fill screen.

```
# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
FPS = 30

# --- functions --- (lower_case names)

def game_loop():
    global move_x_change
    global move_y_change 
    global move_x
    global move_y

    while True:
        # --- events ---

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # ... code ...

        # --- updates (without draws) ---

        move_x +=  move_x_change
        move_y +=  move_y_change

        # --- draws (without updates) ---

        # clear buffer
        screen.fill(WHITE)

        # draw elements
        screen.blit(img_player_1, (move_x, move_y))

        # send buffer on screen
        pygame.display.update()

        # --- FPS ---

        # keep constant speed
        fps.tick(FPS)

# --- main ---

pygame.init()
# ... code ...
```

---

BTW: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Example how to organize code: [simple](https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/blob/master/pygame/__template__/1__simple__.py) and [other templates](https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/tree/master/pygame/__template__)

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. I have been stuck on this issue for 10 hours. I have only been coding for 4 days now without any guides. 

Once again, thanks very much for resolving this and teaching me when i need use uppercase and lowercase

Comment: BTW: [Program Arcade Games With Python And Pygame](http://programarcadegames.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the extra resources :)